# Is the set of all the finite half-open intervals closed under finite intersections and unions?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $\mathcal{J} = \{ [a,b) | a,b \in \mathbb{R}, a \leq b \}$ is $\mathcal{J}$ closed under finite intersections and unions?

- $\mathcal{J}$ is closed under finite intersections
  Let $J_1 =\{ x \in \mathbb{R} | a_1 \leq x <b_1 \}$
  Let $J_2 =\{ x \in \mathbb{R} | a_2 \leq x <b_2 \}$
  where $a_1 \leq a_2 < b_2 < b_1$

Let $J=J_1 \cap J_2 \implies J=\{z \in \mathbb{R} | (a_2 \leq z <b_2) \text{ and } (a_1 \leq z<b_1) \}$
Let $z_1 < z_2$ where $z_1, z_2 \in J$

Now, choose any $\epsilon >0$ and let $t=z_1 + \dfrac{z_2 - z_1}{\epsilon}$

Then $t \leq z_2 < b_2$ and $a_2 \leq z_1 \leq t$

$ \implies z_1 \leq t \leq z_2$ and $t \in J$

---

$J_1 \cup J_2$ is not a half-open interval
but how to show that?
also is the previous proof correct?

Comment: $J_1 \cup J_2$ can be a half-open interval. You have to give one example where it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[a,b) \cap [c,d)$ is empty if $b \le c$ (so equal to $[a.a)$ in $\mathcal{J}$ in that case), and if $b > c$ and $b <d$, the intersection is $[c,b)$, if $b > c$ and $b \ge d$, the intersection is $[c,d)$, all in $\mathcal{J}$.

$[0,1) \cup [2,3)$ is not in $\mathcal{J}$, obviously (it's not order convex). That one example suffices.

Comment: The OP's definition of $\mathcal J$ allows $a=b$ in which case, if the half-open interval is defined in the usual way, it would be $\{x:a\leq x<a\}=\varnothing$. So $\mathcal J$ will be closed under intersections of a finite non-zero number of members.

Answer (score 1):

It is not closed under union. In fact

$[0,1)\cup [2,3)\not \in J$

In any case $J$ is a base for a Topology on $\mathbb{R}$. This Topology is important because it is an example of a Space which it is slitgly different from the Euclidean Topology but that is not separable.